# Why does Lumia 830 show 8MP in camera settings but reviews says it has 10MP camera?

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-830

If I search for *Lumia 830* I end up with reviews like that:

[image: Lumia review on Bing]

But if I open settings in *Lumia Camera 5* it shows to me just **8MP** as the maximum.

[image]

If I analize the picture file metadata it will say something below **10MP** too.

So why does *Lumia 830* is advertised as **10MP** camera but only provides **8MP** photos? It is a O.S. limitation?

Comment: I assume this is due to the oversampling of the PureView camera but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I think 1020 does something like this. 40MP sensor but  38MP photos.

Comment: Same with my 930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more digging and found a great explanation on the [Windows Central Forums](http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-830/333079-camera-aspect-ratio-16-9-4-3-a.html#post2929622) - check it out for more details.

Essentially the lower MPs in the image are a result of how the circular optics project the scene on the sensor and how that circle has to be reduced again to fit the aspect ratio. That's how you lose those 2MP but overall end up with a better field of view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well,
having a look a this can clear your doubt for some extent.
http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-830/334407-lumia-830-doesnt-seem-10mp.html

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that this is normal.  My 1520 is advertised at 20MP and only saves at 16MP.  I think this is similar to how the storage capacity of a drive is always lower than advertised.  As in, there's some technicality that makes the advertised value "true" and it looks good in marketing materials so why not say it.